# Перегрузка конструкторов, какой конструктор будет вызван?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Это UB или есть какое-то правило?

```
class foo {
public:
    foo (int a, int b) { ... }
    foo (char a, char b) { ... }
};

int main ()
{
    foo bar(1,'2');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь нет неопределенного поведения, так как здесь вообще нет никакого поведения, так как код не будет компилироваться.:)

Здесь имеет место неоднозначность вызова конструктора, так как ни один из конструкторов не является лучше другого для заданных аргументов.

Согласно стандарту C++ (13.3.3 Best viable function)

> 1. ...Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better > function than another viable function F2 if for **all arguments**
>      i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and
>      then...

В вашем примере

```
foo (int a, int b) { ... }
foo (char a, char b) { ... }

//...

foo bar(1,'2');
```

первый параметр первого конструктора "лучше" первого параметра второго конструктора так как не требуется преобразования из типа аргумента к типу параметра первого конструктора.

Однако относительно вторых параметров ситуация прямо противоположная, то есть второй параметр второго конструктора "лучше" второго параметра первого конструктора, так как не требуется никакого преобразования из типа аргумента к типу параметра.

Следовательно согласно приведенной цитате ни один из конструкторов не лучше другого конструктора для всех своих параметров и заданных аргументов.

> Это UB или есть какое-то правило?

Это называется разрешением перегрузки, и правила выбора **компилятором** наилучшей функции из перегруженных описаны в стандарте C++.

> 3 **If a best viable function exists and is unique, overload resolution
>   succeeds and produces it as the result**. Otherwise overload resolution
>   fails and the invocation is ill-formed....

Дополнение. При определенных опциях компилятор GCC, например, может скомпилировать код, но при этом выдать предупреждение.
В этом случае он выберет первый конструктор, так как для его второго параметра достаточно применить к аргументу `integral promotion`. В то время как для второго конструктора для его первого параметра требуется преобразование аргумента из типа `int` в тип `char`
А integral promotion имеет "лучший" ранг, чем преобразование (13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences):

> 4 Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact
>   Match is a better conversion than a **Promotion, which is a better
>   conversion than a Conversion**.

Неоднозначность можно было бы (и следовало) устранить посредством явного преобразования, либо написав

```
foo bar( 1, int( '2' ) );
```

и тогда будет вызван первый конструктор, либо написав

```
foo bar( char( 1 ), '2' );
```

и тогда будет вызван второй конструктор.

Comment: Ну если удалить многоточия, то вполне себе скомпилируется. И вызывается конструктор `foo (int a, int b)` (gcc-5.1.0).

Comment: @Flowneee  Я думаю, что компилятор предупреждает, что этот код имеет неоднозначность согласно стандарту C++.

Comment: @Flowneee: Поведение конкретного компилятора не является нормативным, значение имеет только стандарт. Тем более, с `-Wpedantic` и gcc не скомпилирует.

Comment: И все же с т.з. здравого смысла g++ делает верный выбор (очевидно же, что char преобразуется в int без потерь, а не наоборот).

Comment: @avp Он не делает верный выбор, а он из худшего выбирает лучшее.:)

Comment: Точно. В куче ситуаций так и надо поступать. Не по принципу же -- "назло маме отморожу уши"?

Comment: @avp На самом деле здесь вопрос решается программистом просто посредством явного приведения типов, чтобы не ставить ни компилятор, ни читающих его код в тупик.:)

Comment: Тоже можно. И warning исчезнет. Хотя, все это пустое, что так, что этак, поскольку изначальная проблема в самой возможности перегрузки функций.

Comment: Мне кажется, с точки зрения компилятора молча «исправлять» за программиста код неправильно, даже если одна из перегрузок кажется ему _очевидно_ лучшей. «Угаданная» перегрузка может оказаться разрушительной, поэтому программист должен в точности понимать, что он делает. Тем более, он может легко привести типы сам, указав точный тип компилятору и не прибегая к угадыванию.

Comment: На эту тему, [отсюда](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html): _In one notorious incident, Warren added a DWIM feature to the command interpreter used at Xerox PARC. One day another hacker there typed `delete *$` to free up some disk space. (The editor there named backup files by appending `$` to the original file name, so he was trying to delete any backup files left over from old editing sessions.) It happened that there weren't any editor backup files, so DWIM helpfully reported `*$ not found, assuming you meant 'delete *'`. It then started to delete all the files on the disk!_

Answer (score 0):

Да, это UB. Если ее скомпилировать g++, то будет использован конструктор `foo (int a, int b)` и вылезет warning:

> ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second

Clang отказался компилировать, выдав ошибку, майкрософтовский тоже, то есть то, какой конструктор будет выбран, зависит от реализации компилятора (g++ выбирает по принципу какое из плохих преобразований лучше, хотя как он решает, я не очень понял).

Comment: "хотя как он решает, я не очень понял" -- Очевидно же, что char преобразуется в int без потерь, а не наоборот.

Comment: @avp: На теоретической экзотической платформе, где `sizeof(char)` равно `sizeof(int)` и `char` является беззнаковым типом, такое преобразование будет вестимо происходить с потерями.

Comment: @AnT, все равно **все битики** сохранятся (т.е. потерь не будет), да и char в C/C++ вроде бы всегда д.б. знаковым. Т.е. экзотична не платформа (например, Cray) а компилятор.

Comment: @avp: Ну, во-первых, "платформа" в С/С++ - это всегда только компилятор. Компилятор имеет право полностью наплевать на особенности машинной архитектуры и полностью "переписать" эти особенности, если ему так захочется. Во-вторых, нет `char` в С/С++ не обязан быть знаковым.

Comment: С такой позицией уже не поспорить... (кстати, а где Вы реально встречали беззнаковый `char`?)